# Getting invalid double, but the error shows a proper one

Tags: android

My application does some basic arithmetic processes and then adds them to a `TextView`. Because I want them the result be shown up to XX,XX I format my string with `%.2f`. Now, when I try to retrieve this result and use it in another arithmetic process, it gives me an error of:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "8,86" (or any number for that matter)
```

How can I make the second process convert the string from the `TextView`without getting an error?

**process 1**

```
int newProductQuantity = Integer.valueOf(productQuantity.getText().toString());
double newProductPrice = Double.valueOf(productPrice.getText().toString());
double newProductVAT = Double.valueOf(productVat.getText().toString());
double newProductPriceSum = ((newProductPrice + (newProductPrice * (newProductVAT / 100))) * newProductQuantity);
String newProductPriceSumTexta = String.format("%.2f", newProductPriceSum);
productPriceSum.setText(newProductPriceSumTexta);
```

**process 2**

```
double newOrderFinalLastSum = Double.parseDouble(newOrderFinalSum.getText().toString());
double newOrderFinalNewSum = Double.parseDouble(productPriceSum.getText().toString());
double newOrderFinalOmegaSum = newOrderFinalLastSum + newOrderFinalNewSum; //error is here
String newOrderFinalOmegaSumText = String.format("%.2f", newOrderFinalOmegaSum);
newOrderFinalSum.setText(newOrderFinalOmegaSumText);
```

Comment: decimal part delimiter should be . (dot), not ,(comma)

Comment: Do not seperate doubles with a comma, use a dot instead `8.86`

Comment: @AlexanderZhak that depends on your locale.

Comment: @blackbelt So the `String.format` is changing my `.` to `,`. Can I use `String.format` to change the way my decimal point is displayed?

Comment: you should specify a Locale. If you want to use `.` instead of `,` use `String.format(Locale.UK,...`

Comment: @blackbelt Thanks! It worked. If you could just answer it to the main thread so I could vote it as correct, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is `Locale`  related. If you want always a dot `.` as separator, you should specify a `Locale` that use it. You can use `format` method that takes as first parameter a `Locale` object. For instance

```
String.format(Locale.UK,...
```

From the documentation of `public static String format(Locale l, String format, Object... args)`

> Returns a formatted string using the specified locale, format string,
>   and arguments.

where

> l - The locale to apply during formatting. If l is null then no
>   localization is applied.